# Adding a new tab using client side API in Telerik MVC TabStrip control

Tags: telerik-mvc

Does anyone know how to add a tab in Telerik's MVC TabStrip using Client Side API ? There is nothing in documentation and no code in tabstrip javascript too. I am hoping some one might have done this before.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: After googling a lot , i got [this](http://www.aspnetwiki.com/telerik-mvc:dynamically-add-a-tab-to-the-tabstrip) post. It solved my problem of adding new tab using client API. you will have to download telerik.extensions.js and register it in _layout.cshtml and then just call addTab on your tabstrip instance like this: $("#customerTabs").data("tTabStrip").addTab({ text: 'customer #' + custId, html: "<div>some customer</div>"});

Comment: If you managed to completely solve your problem, you should post it as an actual answer and accept it.  Just including it in the comments may make it hard for a future visitor to see.

Answer (score 1):

After googling a lot , i got this post. It solved my problem of adding new tab using client API. you will have to download `telerik.extensions.js` and register it in `_layout.cshtml` and then just call addTab on your tabstrip instance like this:

```
$("#customerTabs").data("tTabStrip").addTab({ text: 'customer #' + custId, html: "<div>some customer</div>"});
```